# Changing position attribute with media query doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have two Divs (fixed (for background images) and absolute(for text)). The layout is like this: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e9vyu/)

```
#hintergrund {
    z-index: -9999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#textbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    max-width: 28em;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

I try to change the position attributes of the two divs from fixed to static and from absolute to static with a media query to achieve this: [After Mediaquery](http://jsfiddle.net/e9vyu/1/).

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {

#hintergrund {
    position: static;
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
}    


#textbox {
    position: static;
    margin-left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: white;
}
```

}

Now my problem:

I reload the page at fullscreen and lower the viewportsize to "activate" the mediaquery --> the #textbox is still behaving like position absolut BUT takes the width and margin attributes from the mediaquery.

When I reload the page under mediaquery resolution (everything is as expected) and rise the viewportsize above the mediaquery--> the #textbox is still behaving like position static BUT takes the width etc from the normal css ([looks like this](http://jsfiddle.net/e9vyu/4/).)

So my conclusion so far is, that the media query isn't capable of changing position attribute correctly, or did I missed something?

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}` is a better way to declare the media query. You might need !important declaration.

Comment: wow that's it. I added !important to all position attributes and it worked. Thanks a lot! Does this solution works with every browser?

Comment: Yep for the most part. IE8 and media queries don't play nice without a few JS libraries.

Comment: !important is not the way to go

Comment: Yeah thats ok. IE8 is about 5% of Users. So thats tolerable :D (http://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/158095/umfrage/meistgenutzte-browser-im-internet-weltweit/)

Comment: @vlrprbttst what would you suggest? I couldn't find another solution.

Comment: Make sure the media query is below or after the "normal" CSS rules so they take precedence

Comment: my media querys are at the bottom of my css rules. But also placing them in a seperate CSS File didn't make it work. Any other suggestions? And why shouldn't I use !important? Is there something I have to keep an eye of?

Comment: can you post a fiddle with your mediaqueries in?

Comment: it's the same I already posted above, just with !important behind both position: static